# Static Method which uses reflection

Tags: java, reflection, static

I am currently experimenting with reflection and I recently came across a question. I have this method, which calculates the size (unit: bytes) of a class consisting only of primitive typed fields (excluding booleans) as follows:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Foo {

    // [...]   

    // Works only for classes with primitive typed fields (excluding booleans)
    public int getSize() {
        int size = 0;

        for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                Object obj = f.get(this);
                Field objField = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("SIZE");
                int fieldSize = (int) objField.get(obj);
                size += fieldSize / Byte.SIZE;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return size;
    }

}
```

As you can see the method cannot be static, since it contains non-static stuff like `getClass()` and `this`. However, for every instance of this class the return value of `getSize()` will be the same, which also holds for every class which extends `Foo` (of course, with a different value). Hence, conceptually `getSize()` has a static nature.

Is there a way to make this method static? I thought of using a static class reference like `Foo.class` to get around `getClass()` but this would basically destroy the semantics of `getSize()` for classes which extend `Foo`. I currently do not think it is possible since static methods are not inherited, but I am not 100% sure if there might be a little tweak to handle this issue.

Comment: If you want to make the method static then you have to change it to take an argument of type `Foo`.

Comment: Both answers suggesting passing Foo as an argument are valid.; You may also want to consider whether it is in the nature of Foo to have such a method, or whether you would want to externalise it to some utility Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's wrong with doing something like

```
public static int getSize(Object parent) {
    int size = 0;

    for (Field f : parent.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        try {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Object obj = f.get(parent);
            Field objField = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("SIZE");
            int fieldSize = (Integer) objField.get(obj);
            size += fieldSize / Byte.SIZE;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return size;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't name the object "parent" but the rest looks o.k.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getClass(), you could use Foo.class to obtain a reference to the Class object.

However, if you need an instance of class Foo, you still have to create it someplace. If the class has a default constructor, you could use Foo.class.newInstance(). Otherwise, use reflection to obtain a list of constructors and call the correct one.